# How to make the 2 applicationContexts created in a Spring-MVC app children of a global applicationContext

Tags: java, web-applications, spring-mvc

I have 3 application contexts:

- A global context which is responsible for launching Jetty servlet container, launched from main()
- An applicationContext parent to each webapp in jetty (started by SpringSecurity
- n xyz-servlet contexts for each webapp (I run 1 webapp)

Spring managed creating a parent-child relationship for the latter two contexts.

Now I would like to add a simple global properties service to the first context and have it visible to the others (I could add it to applicationContext, but I may use it elsewhere outside the webapp context later and want to plan for that).

Since I didn't manage creation of the other two contexts (they were created by the dispatcher servlet and spring security which were launched from web.xml) I'm not clear how and where I should access them to define the first as the parent (well, only applicationContext should take the global context as its parent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The parent-child relationship between (1) and (2) can be managed by the `ContextLoaderListener` that you have in your `web.xml`.

Specifically, have a look at the [javadoc for `ContextLoader.loadParentContext()`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/context/ContextLoader.html#loadParentContext%28javax.servlet.ServletContext%29). This documents how the `ContextLoaderListener` can locate context (1). It assumes that this global context was initialised via `ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator`, which you may or may not have used to create that context.

If you *did* use `ContextSingletonBeanFactoryLocator`, then it should be trivial, just follow the instructions in the javadoc.  if you used some other way of bootstrapping the global context, then you can subclass `ContextLoaderListener`, override the `loadParentContext()` method to locate your global context, then use that in `web.xml` instead of the standard `ContextLoaderListener`.